# Hide the default calendar list column

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I want to hide/delete the default columns which comes in calendar list. I tried it through SharePoint manager but that didn't work . Any other approach for doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new content type, where the parent is "event". See here:

[image]

Then you could add the columns you want and add the "CustomEvent" content type to your calendar. I think that should be the way.

Comment: worked for me. This is how to associate the event with the calendar list: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-917366ae-f7a2-47ad-87a5-9689a1884e60

Answer (score 0):

I Did it using this :-

Enable Content Type and Hide the Field:
This will hide the field from All list forms - NewForm, EditForm and DispForm. 
Go to List Settings and enable content type by clicking "Advanced settings" and then choose "Yes" for "Allow management of content types?".
Once done, You see "Content Types" in list settings. Click on "Item" link.sharepoint hide field
Select the Field to hide 
sharepoint hide columns on form
Choose "Hidden" under column setting ..

Hope this works for all . 
PS - I implemented this in SP 2010